# Registration and scope of unittest addTypeEqualityFunc()

Tags: python, python-unittest

Python's `unittest` framework defines the [`addTypeEqualityFunc`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc) method, which "Registers a type-specific method called by assertEqual() to check if two objects of exactly the same typeobj (not subclasses) compare equal."

What are the scope an mechanism of this registration? The documentation does not discuss either, and "python registration" is resistant to searching.

Mostly, I am curious about whether this "registration" is some kind of assignment in local scope, or if Python has a broader concept of registration I haven't been able to unearth in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It applies to the *current test* only. Python unittest does not have some broader concept of "registration" in this case.  Both the tests below will pass:

```
# run these tests with "python -m unittest" in same directory as this file.

from unittest import TestCase

class Potato:
    pass

def potato_compare(potato1, potato2, msg=None):
    return True

class Test1(TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        spud = Potato()
        yam = Potato()
        self.addTypeEqualityFunc(Potato, potato_compare)
        self.assertEqual(spud, yam)

    def test_two(self):
        spud = Potato()
        yam = Potato()
        self.assertNotEqual(spud, yam)
```

If you want it to apply to every test, you can add it to `setUp`:

```
class Test2(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.addTypeEqualityFunc(Potato, potato_compare)

    def test_one(self):
        spud = Potato()
        yam = Potato()
        self.assertEqual(spud, yam)

    def test_two(self):
        spud = Potato()
        yam = Potato()
        self.assertEqual(spud, yam)
```

*Warning:* This functionality [does not recurse into containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505258/assertequal-custom-comparison-of-list-item). For example, `[spud]` and `[yam]` will not be recognized as equal lists.